# How to get final links from find_all('a') as a list?

Tags: python, list, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

```
import requests
import re
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
respond = requests.get("http://www.kulugyminiszterium.hu/dtwebe/Irodak.aspx")
print(respond)

soup = BeautifulSoup(respond.text, 'html.parser')

for link in soup.find_all('a'):
    links = link.get('href')

    linki_bloc = ('http://www.kulugyminiszterium.hu/dtwebe/'+links).replace(' ', '%20' )
    print(linki_bloc)

value = linki_bloc
print(value.split())
```

I am trying to use the results of `find_all('a')` as a `list`. The only thing that succeeds for me is the last link.

It seems to me that the problem is the results as a list of links deselected `\n`. I tried many ways to get rid of the new line character but failed. Saving to a file (e.g. .txt) also fails, saving only the last link.

Comment: Please, provide what you expect and what you get instead. What does "succeeds" mean? Your code prints all the links for me. The last two lines only run once because they are not in the for loop

Comment: Are you just trying to get a list of HREFs?

Comment: Success will be a list[] containing objects - links

Answer (score 0):

Close to your goal, but you overwrite the result wit each iteration - Simply append your manipulated links to a `list` with `list comprehension` directly:

```
['http://www.kulugyminiszterium.hu/dtwebe/'+link.get('href').replace(' ', '%20' ) for link in soup.find_all('a')]
```

or as in your example:

```
links = []
for link in soup.find_all('a'):
    links.append('http://www.kulugyminiszterium.hu/dtwebe/'+link.get('href').replace(' ', '%20' ))
```

##### Example

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
respond = requests.get("http://www.kulugyminiszterium.hu/dtwebe/Irodak.aspx")

soup = BeautifulSoup(respond.text, 'html.parser')

links = []
for link in soup.find_all('a'):
    links.append('http://www.kulugyminiszterium.hu/dtwebe/'+link.get('href').replace(' ', '%20' ))

links
```

Comment: Thank you! This is what I was looking for. In my attempts I've been circling around it but haven't hit it.